# VS 2023 'var' suggestions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, var

```
foreach (int dirId in dirIds)
{
    serieIds.AddRange((from serie in TableDataGrid.TargetBaseContext.Series
                       where serie.RepertoireId == dirId
                       select serie.SerieId).ToList());
}
```

In the above code, VS suggests to use `var` instead of `int`. Why should we, if only `int` is wanted ? Is there any way to tell VS not to suggest such modification ?

I just try to understand whether I miss something when thinking that `int` is better than `var`.

Comment: What's the compile-time type of `dirIds`?

Comment: Yes. You can configure that preference in settings. I don't think it will improve clarity in this case however.

Comment: `if only int is wanted` but is it?  What if `dirIds` changes to hold `long`s?  In databases ID columns are typically bigint/long, not int, because an `int` only holds 2M positive values and can get exhausted *very* quickly. It's not just that a 2M-row table isn't considered big, but the application itself can easily create more than 2M rows very quickly. Using `var` means you won't have to change your code while still having type safety. Using `int` on the other hand would cause an unexpected cast , compilation errors or worse, overflow into negative values

Comment: You could simplify and speed up this code by almost N if you rewrite it as `var serieIds=TableDataGrid.TargetBaseContext.Series.Where(s=>dirIds.Contains(s.RepertoireId)).Select(s=>s.SerieId).ToList()`. This single query will return *all* matching SerieId in a List<> with the same type as `SerieId`. If you later decide to change to an array with `ToArray()` or a set with `ToHashSet()`  you won't have to change the variable definition or the rest of the query. If `dirIds` is a `HashSet` instead of a list or array, `Contains` is an `O(1)` operation, so searching for matching IDs becomes  O(N)

Comment: Pros: [Why You Should Always Use the ‘var’ Keyword in C#](https://web.archive.org/web/20220517074247/http://blog.michaelbrennan.net/2010/06/why-you-should-always-use-var-keyword.html). Cons: [Why you should no longer use var in C#](https://schwabencode.com/blog/2022/09/09/csharp-why-you-should-not-use-var-anymore)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio, in the menu **Tools > Options...** you can navigate to **Text Editor > C# > Code Style > General** and configure **'var' preferences**:

[image]

These are my personal preferences:

- **For built-in types** `var` adds no value and only makes the code less readable
  => **Prefer explicit type**.
- **When the variable type is apparent** as in `var dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();`, there is no point in repeating the type name. `var` makes the code more readable
  => **Prefer 'var'**.
- **Elsewhere**: And then there are all these other cases. Sometimes you want to see the type as in `List<PersonDto> = GetData();`. In other cases - very often LINQ queries - the type names might become quite complex and add not much value. Or are you interested in the fact that a query returns a `IOrderedEnumerable<(string Key, IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Polygon>> Polygons)>`? Here, I set the Severity to *Refactoring only*. This lets me refactor the code easily at any time without Visual Studio spamming me with irrelevant messages
  => **Prefer explicit type** + **Refactoring only**.